# GA4 Reports not grouping events properly?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

For this one particular event, I'm seeing the same events not being grouped together and I can't figure out why. This screenshot is from the standard GA4 event page filtered by the particular event that is having issues.

[image]

The text is 100% the same for both of these events. I've base64 encoded both of the param texts and they match perfectly. When testing via debug mode, I am only seeing a single event being fired. I cannot understand for the life of me why these would not be grouped together when from what I understand it should be grouping on the value of this custom parameter value.

Anything else that I could check?